# Save and Load nested Map into text file using Java

Tags: java, text, dictionary, load, save

I have a nested MAP. I want to save these Map in a text file and then use this file in another projects. I can save outerMap correctly, however I need an efficient code to load this file into same Maps (I use '#' to separating key of outerMap and its innerMap).

```
Map <String, Map <String,Double>> outerMap= new HashMap<>();
Map <String,Double> innerMap= new HashMap<>();
   .
   .
   .

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("e:\\t.txt", "UTF-8");
Iterator it = outerMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       writer.println(pairs.getKey() + "#" + pairs.getValue());
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: do you need the file to be readable? use `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: I may convert Map to JSON format. Save it into text-file. It will be easy approach to restore Map later.

Comment: @epoch, Thanks, content of that file does not change, In fact I need to read that file into my nested Map.

Comment: @Dmitry Tsechoev, do you have that code for save and load nested map into JSON?

Comment: @Masoud, give me some time. I'll write code. And in my first comment must be 'You may' instead 'I may'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your question in comment:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Map<String, Map<String, Double>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Double> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("1", 1.0);
innerMap.put("2", 2.0);

outerMap.put("key1", innerMap);

String json = gson.toJson(outerMap);

Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("", "myfile.txt");
Files.write(path, json.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));

outerMap = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>(){}.getType());

for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Double>> outerEntry: outerMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(outerEntry.getKey());
    innerMap = outerEntry.getValue();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> innerEntry: innerMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("    " + innerEntry.getKey() + "->" + innerEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output:

> key1
>       2->2.0
>       1->1.0

You need use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

If you don't need human readable content in text-file, you can use approach, suggested in the first comment:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Double> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("1", 1.0);
innerMap.put("2", 2.0);

outerMap.put("key1", innerMap);

// write to file

try (ObjectOutput objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile2.txt", false)))) {
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(outerMap);
} catch (Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
}

// read from file

try (ObjectInput objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile2.txt")))) {
    outerMap = (Map<String, Map<String, Double>>) objectInputStream.readObject();
} catch (Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will have your Map on 'outerMap' reference.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds pretty straightforward to me.

(Assuming you want to load the values of the file into innerMap)

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("e:\\t.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String buffer;
while((buffer = reader.readLine()) != null){
    String[] pairs = buffer.split("#");
    innerMap.put(pairs[0],Double.parseDouble(pairs[1]));
}
```

Pepper it with safety checks where you deem necessary.

**NOTE** : Sample code is written blindly and might be subject to careless mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, but your code has a error: "ouble cannot converted tp Map< String, Double>.

Comment: @Masoud That is because you are trying to put the double in the place where `Map<String,Double>` should be. If your `innerMap` object is `Map<String,Double>` then this will work, if your `innerMap` object is a `Map<String,Map<String,Double>>`, then you will have to nest them yourself as you see fit. `pairs[0]` from my example is the `pairs.getKey()` from your example and `pairs[1]` from my example is the `pairs.getValue()` from your example.